# Getting the values of a dictionary of a dictionary in swift

Tags: swift, firebase

I am running a firebase query in swift to return a dictionary that prints:

```
["Adonis": 

{
bio = There;

email = "adonis@aol.com";

 fname = Adonis;

lname = p;

location = Here;

}]
```

I want to access dictionary["Adonis"]["bio"] but I am unable to.

Here is the code:

```
    `Database.database().reference().child("Users").queryOrdered(byChild:"email").queryEqual(toValue: email).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] else {return}`

    print(dictionary)

    }) 

    {(Error) in

     print("Failed to fetch: ", Error)

     }
```

I have tried force unwrapping values and only get a "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" error. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Try `if let adonis = dictionary["adonis"] as? [String: Any] { print("adonis value: \(adonis)"); if let bio = adonis["bio"] as? String { print("Bio: \(bio)")} }`?

Comment: A review of the Getting Started Guide [Read data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write) will help. The data you want is contained in the `snapshot` and I would advise not 
"converting" or using dictionaries with Firebase - use firebase snapshots as snapshots to retrieve child data `let bio = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "bio").value as? String ?? "No bio"`. You may also want to remove your query as it's not needed; if you know the specific path to the child `Users/email`, simply use `getDocument` to retrieve it.